# How to display a PDF from a phonegap app in Android 8

Tags: android, pdf, phonegap, inappbrowser, android-8.1-oreo

I manage to display PDF with phonegap inappbrowser in ios and Android 6 but not Android 8.

Here is the code :

```
      if (platform !== 'Android') {
        var ref = window.open(
          decodeURI(pdf.filepath),
          '_blank',
          `location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes`
        )
      } else {
        var ref = window.open(
          decodeURI(pdf.filepath),
          '_system',
          `location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes`
        )
      }
```

The button that trigger this code open a new window, but she’s remains empty. I tried with a wrong path, it shows an error so it’s not a path problem.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I managed to display PDF on Android > 6. **It’s not possible to display PDF through inappbrowser for Android > 6** (2 fulltime days of testing and googling...).

I used **cordova-plugin-file-opener2**. But what’s important to know (I didn’t until yesterday), **you can’t test plugins via "phonegap serve" + phonegap app on device !!** You need to build the apk, install it and then test it. This important point make me loose my nerves on various plugins...

That’s all.